# How to setup MonoCross and Xamarin SDK for windows 7 pro

Tags: monocross

I need to develop cross platform app. I hv downloaded thee MonoCross http://monocross.net/download But there is no setUp for installation.

I am not familiar and confused as there is no note on how to setUp the platform and install the Xamarin SDK. Would appreciate if you can guide me and provide me the tutorial links.

I am using Windows 7 pro and I have Visual studio 2010 for windows phone.

Thanks